# Scale-independent Pixels font size of text in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, font-size

Hello I am making an android application where I am giving text size is in `sp` as recommended.

I am setting my font size to `25sp` to the `TextView`. Suppose here if user pick "Large" font of the device from the settings of the device and later update it to "Normal" then my application font also vary according to that.

But Is there any calculation such that I can calculate what would be size of font if it is "Large" and "Normal" ?

Screenshot of the device font settings

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can get view dimensions, but you do not really need to care in most cases. If you set size in `sp` then it means you are aware what that unit means and you expect this behaviour. If you do not like fonts size being changed, simply use `dp`

Comment: I accepted your nice answer but please let me know if you know the calculation what would be size of font if it is "Large" and "Normal" ?